# Establishing secure connection from a third party server to Salesforce using certificates

Tags: integration, certificates

How can I establish secure connection from my server to salesforce. I need to make a secured call from my abc server using java language and retrieve information from salesforce, using certificates.

Almost all salesforce documentations explains it the other way like making a 2 way mutual authentication call from salesforce to other server but my requirement is just opposite. Eg.
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Making_Authenticated_Web_Service_Callouts_Using_Two-Way_SSL

Comment: i think you will need connected app here. Read ConnectedApp in sf and see if you can use them.

Comment: Basically I want to know how to make secured call in to saleaforce uaing certificates.

Answer (score 1):

The OAuth 2.0 JWT Bearer Token Flow is one way to do this. It allows a certificate you create in Salesforce to be used to authenticate requests from an external server. The [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm) describes the setup steps and includes sample Java code for the client-side. The flow is also described in [Digging Deeper into OAuth 2.0 on Force.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com).